# Parallel processing on rasterstack using Raster and Parallel Packages

Tags: raster, r, parallel-processing, bfast

I want to run BFAST on a raster stack (768 Landsat NDVI) in parallel processing.  In order to illustrate the problem, I used the following reproducible code:

Load necessary packages;

```
library(raster)
library(zoo)
library(xts)
library(bfast)
```

Create a reproducible rasterstack;

```
set.seed(123)
r1 <- raster(nrows = 6, ncols = 5, res = 30, xmn = 267195, xmx = 267375, ymn = 4016985, ymx = 4017135)
rr <- lapply(1:768, function(i) setValues(r1, runif(ncell(r1), min = -10000, max = 10000)))
ndvi <- stack(rr)
crs(ndvi) <- "+proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

Create date function;

```
dt <-as.data.frame(as.Date(c(
  '2017-01-03','2017-02-04','2018-11-22','2019-05-17','2013-04-14','2013-04-30',
  '2013-05-16','2013-06-01','2013-06-17','2013-07-03','2013-07-19','2013-08-04',
  '2013-08-20','2013-09-05','2013-10-07','2013-10-23','2013-11-08','2013-11-24',
  '2013-12-10','2013-12-26','2014-01-11','2014-01-27','2014-02-12','2014-02-28', 
  '2014-04-01','2014-04-17','2014-05-03','2014-05-19','2014-06-04','2014-06-20',
  '2014-07-06','2014-07-22','2014-08-07','2014-08-23','2014-09-08','2014-09-24',
  '2014-10-10','2014-10-26','2014-11-11','2014-11-27','2014-12-13','2014-12-29',
  '2015-01-14','2015-01-30','2015-02-15','2015-03-19','2015-04-04','2015-04-20',
  '2015-05-06','2015-05-22','2015-06-07','2015-06-23','2015-07-09','2015-07-25',
  '2015-08-10','2015-08-26','2015-09-11','2015-09-27','2015-10-13','2015-10-29',
  '2015-11-14','2015-11-30','2015-12-16','2016-01-01','2016-01-17','2016-02-02',
  '2016-02-18','2016-03-05','2016-03-21','2016-04-06','2016-04-22','2016-05-08',
  '2016-05-24','2016-06-25','2016-07-11','2016-07-27','2016-08-12','2016-08-28',
  '2016-09-13','2016-09-29','2016-10-15','2016-10-31','2016-11-16','2016-12-02',
  '2016-12-18','2017-01-19','2017-02-20','2017-03-08','2017-03-24','2017-04-09',
  '2017-04-25','2017-05-11','2017-05-27','2017-06-12','2017-06-28','2017-07-14',
  '2017-07-30','2017-08-15','2017-08-31','2017-09-16','2017-10-02','2017-10-18',
  '2017-11-03','2017-12-05','2017-12-21','2018-01-06','2018-01-22','2018-02-07',
  '2018-02-23','2018-03-11','2018-04-12','2018-04-28','2018-05-14','2018-05-30', 
  '2018-06-15','2018-07-01','2018-07-17','2018-08-02','2018-08-18','2018-09-03',
  '2018-09-19','2018-10-05','2018-10-21','2018-11-06','2018-12-08','2018-12-24',
  '2019-01-09','2019-01-25','2019-02-10','2019-02-26','2019-03-14','2019-03-30',
  '2019-04-15','2019-05-01','2019-06-02','2019-06-18','2019-07-04','2019-07-20',
  '2019-08-05','2019-08-21','2019-09-06','2019-09-22','2019-10-08','2019-10-24',
  '2019-11-09','2019-11-25','2001-01-31','2002-03-23','2002-11-02','2007-03-21',
  '2008-02-04','2010-05-16','2010-06-17','2012-01-14','2012-12-15','2013-01-16',
  '2013-05-08','2013-12-02','2014-03-24','2014-04-25','2014-05-11','2015-02-07',
  '2015-02-23','2015-08-02','2016-02-10','2016-03-13','2016-12-10','2018-04-20',
  '2018-05-06','2019-01-01','2019-07-28','1999-08-06','1999-09-07','1999-10-25',
  '1999-12-12','2000-01-29','2000-02-14','2000-03-01','2000-03-17','2000-04-18',
  '2000-05-20','2000-06-05','2000-06-21','2000-08-24','2000-09-09','2000-10-11',
  '2000-10-27','2000-11-28','2000-12-30','2001-01-15','2001-03-04','2001-03-20',
  '2001-04-21','2001-05-23','2001-06-08','2001-08-11','2001-09-28','2002-01-02',
  '2002-01-18','2002-04-08','2002-04-24','2002-06-11','2002-08-30','2002-10-01',
  '2003-03-10','2003-03-26','2003-04-27','2003-05-13','2003-05-29','2003-07-16',
  '2003-09-02','2003-09-18','2003-10-20','2004-01-24','2004-03-12','2004-03-28',
  '2004-04-13','2004-05-15','2004-06-16','2004-07-02','2004-07-18','2004-09-04',
  '2004-09-20','2004-10-22','2004-11-07','2004-11-23','2004-12-09','2004-12-25',
  '2005-01-10','2005-03-15','2005-03-31','2005-04-16','2005-05-02','2005-05-18',
  '2005-06-03','2005-06-19','2005-07-05','2005-07-21','2005-08-06','2005-08-22',
  '2005-09-07','2005-09-23','2005-10-09','2005-12-12','2006-04-03','2006-04-19',
  '2006-05-05','2006-05-21','2006-06-06','2006-06-22','2006-07-08','2006-07-24',
  '2006-08-09','2006-08-25','2006-09-10','2006-09-26','2006-11-13','2007-02-01',
  '2007-03-05','2007-04-22','2007-05-08','2007-06-09','2007-06-25','2007-07-11',
  '2007-07-27','2007-08-12','2007-08-28','2007-09-13','2007-09-29','2007-10-15',
  '2007-10-31','2007-11-16','2007-12-02','2008-01-19','2008-02-20','2008-03-23',
  '2008-04-24','2008-05-10','2008-05-26','2008-06-11','2008-06-27','2008-07-13',
  '2008-07-29','2008-08-14','2008-08-30','2008-09-15','2008-10-01','2008-10-17',
  '2008-11-18','2008-12-04','2009-01-05','2009-01-21','2009-03-10','2009-03-26',
  '2009-05-13','2009-05-29','2009-06-14','2009-06-30','2009-07-16','2009-08-01',
  '2009-08-17','2009-09-02','2009-09-18','2009-10-04','2009-10-20','2009-11-05',
  '2009-11-21','2009-12-07','2009-12-23','2010-01-08','2010-03-13','2010-04-14',
  '2010-06-01','2010-07-03','2010-07-19','2010-08-04','2010-08-20','2010-09-05',
  '2010-09-21','2010-10-07','2010-10-23','2010-11-08','2010-11-24','2010-12-10',
  '2010-12-26','2011-01-11','2011-01-27','2011-03-16','2011-05-03','2011-05-19',
  '2011-06-04','2011-06-20','2011-07-06','2011-07-22','2011-08-07','2011-08-23',
  '2011-09-08','2011-09-24','2011-10-10','2011-10-26','2011-11-11','2011-11-27',
  '2011-12-13','2011-12-29','2012-01-30','2012-02-15','2012-03-02','2012-03-18',
  '2012-04-03','2012-04-19','2012-05-05','2012-05-21','2012-06-06','2012-06-22',
  '2012-07-08','2012-07-24','2012-08-09','2012-08-25','2012-09-10','2012-09-26',
  '2012-10-12','2012-10-28','2012-11-13','2012-12-31','2013-02-01','2013-02-17',
  '2013-03-05','2013-03-21','2013-04-22','2013-05-24','2013-06-09','2013-06-25',
  '2013-07-11','2013-07-27','2013-08-12','2013-08-28','2013-09-13','2013-09-29',
  '2013-10-15','2013-10-31','2013-11-16','2013-12-18','2014-01-03','2014-01-19',
  '2014-02-04','2014-02-20','2014-03-08','2014-04-09','2014-05-27','2014-06-12',
  '2014-06-28','2014-07-14','2014-07-30','2014-08-31','2014-09-16','2014-10-02',
  '2014-10-18','2014-11-03','2014-11-19','2014-12-05','2014-12-21','2015-01-06',
  '2015-01-22','2015-03-11','2015-03-27','2015-04-12','2015-04-28','2015-05-14',
  '2015-05-30','2015-06-15','2015-07-01','2015-07-17','2015-08-18','2015-09-03',
  '2015-09-19','2015-10-05','2015-10-21','2015-11-06','2015-11-22','2015-12-08',
  '2015-12-24','2016-01-09','2016-01-25','2016-02-26','2016-03-29','2016-04-14',
  '2016-04-30','2016-05-16','2016-06-17','2016-07-03','2016-07-19','2016-08-04',
  '2016-08-20','2016-09-05','2016-09-21','2016-10-07','2016-10-23','2016-11-08',
  '2016-11-24','2016-12-26','2017-01-11','2017-01-27','2017-02-12','2017-02-28',
  '2017-04-01','2017-04-17','2017-05-03','2017-05-19','2017-06-04','2017-06-20',
  '2017-07-06','2017-07-22','2017-08-07','2017-08-23','2017-09-08','2017-09-24',
  '2017-10-10','2017-10-26','2017-11-11','2017-11-27','2017-12-13','2017-12-29',
  '2018-01-14','2018-01-30','2018-02-15','2018-03-03','2018-03-19','2018-04-04',
  '2018-05-22','2018-06-07','2018-06-23','2018-07-09','2018-07-25','2018-08-10',
  '2018-08-26','2018-09-11','2018-09-27','2018-10-13','2018-10-29','2018-11-14',
  '2018-11-30','2018-12-16','2019-01-17','2019-02-02','2019-02-18','2019-03-06',
  '2019-03-22','2019-04-07','2019-04-23','2019-05-09','2019-05-25','2019-06-10',
  '2019-06-26','2019-07-12','2019-08-13','2019-08-29','2019-09-14','2019-09-30',
  '2019-10-16','2019-11-01','2019-11-17','2019-12-03','1988-03-24','1989-12-08',
  '1991-01-28','1991-02-13','1991-03-17','1991-05-20','1991-12-14','1992-03-19',
  '1993-03-22','1993-12-03','1994-01-20','1994-03-09','1994-09-17','1994-12-22',
  '1995-03-28','1995-09-20','1996-01-26','1997-03-17','1997-04-02','1998-03-04',
  '1998-03-20','1998-06-24','1998-07-26','1999-01-02','1999-03-07','2001-03-28',
  '2001-06-16','2002-01-10','2009-02-14','2009-03-18','2009-05-05','2011-02-04',
  '1988-01-04','1988-01-20','1988-06-12','1988-06-28','1988-08-15','1988-08-31',
  '1988-11-03','1988-11-19','1988-12-05','1989-01-22','1989-02-07','1989-04-12',
  '1989-05-14','1989-05-30','1989-09-30','1989-10-21','1989-12-24','1990-01-25',
  '1990-02-26','1990-03-30','1990-04-15','1990-05-17','1990-06-02','1990-08-21',
  '1990-09-06','1990-10-08','1990-10-24','1991-03-01','1991-04-18','1991-06-05',
  '1991-07-07','1991-08-08','1991-09-09','1991-11-12','1992-02-16','1992-03-03',
  '1992-04-20','1992-06-07','1992-06-23','1992-07-09','1992-10-29','1992-11-14',
  '1992-11-30','1992-12-16','1993-01-17','1993-02-02','1993-02-18','1993-03-06',
  '1993-04-07','1993-05-09','1993-05-25','1993-06-10','1993-07-12','1993-07-28',
  '1993-08-13','1993-09-30','1993-10-16','1993-11-17','1993-12-19','1994-01-04',
  '1994-02-21','1994-04-26','1994-05-12','1994-05-28','1994-06-13','1994-06-29',
  '1994-07-15','1994-07-31','1994-08-16','1994-09-01','1994-10-03','1994-11-04',
  '1994-11-20','1995-01-07','1995-01-23','1995-02-24','1995-03-12','1995-05-15',
  '1995-05-31','1995-06-16','1995-07-02','1995-07-18','1995-10-06','1995-10-22',
  '1995-11-23','1995-12-09','1995-12-25','1996-01-10','1996-02-11','1996-02-27',
  '1996-03-14','1996-03-30','1996-04-15','1996-05-01','1996-06-18','1996-07-04',
  '1996-07-20','1996-08-05','1996-08-21','1996-09-06','1996-09-22','1996-10-08',
  '1996-10-24','1997-01-28','1997-02-13','1997-04-18','1997-05-20','1997-06-05',
  '1997-07-07','1997-08-08','1997-08-24','1997-09-09','1997-10-11','1997-11-28',
  '1998-02-16','1998-04-05','1998-04-21','1998-05-07','1998-05-23','1998-06-08',
  '1998-07-10','1998-08-11','1998-08-27','1998-09-12','1998-09-28','1998-10-14',
  '1998-10-30','1998-11-15','1998-12-01','1998-12-17','1999-01-18','1999-02-03',
  '1999-02-19','1999-03-23','1999-04-08','1999-04-24','1999-05-26','1999-07-29',
  '1999-08-14','1999-08-30','1999-10-17','1999-12-04','1999-12-20','2000-01-05',
  '2000-01-21','2000-02-06','2000-02-22','2000-03-25','2000-04-10','2000-05-12',
  '2000-05-28','2000-06-13','2000-06-29','2000-08-16','2000-09-01','2000-09-17',
  '2000-10-19','2000-11-20','2001-01-07','2001-01-23','2001-02-24','2001-05-15',
  '2001-05-31','2001-07-02','2001-07-18','2001-08-03','2001-09-04','2001-09-20',
  '2001-10-06','2001-10-22','2001-11-07','2001-12-09','2001-12-25','2002-02-11',
  '2002-03-31','2002-05-18','2002-06-19','2002-07-21','2002-08-06','2008-04-16',
  '2008-05-18','2008-06-03','2008-06-19','2008-07-05','2008-10-09','2008-10-25',
  '2008-11-26','2009-03-02','2009-04-03','2009-04-19','2009-05-21','2009-06-06',
  '2009-06-22','2009-07-08','2009-07-24','2009-08-09','2009-08-25','2009-09-10',
  '2009-09-26','2009-10-12','2009-10-28','2009-11-13','2009-11-29','2009-12-15',
  '2010-01-16','2010-03-05','2010-05-24','2010-06-09','2010-06-25','2010-07-11',
  '2010-08-12','2010-08-28','2010-09-13','2010-09-29','2010-10-15','2010-10-31',
  '2010-11-16','2010-12-02','2010-12-18','2011-01-03','2011-01-19','2011-03-08',
  '2011-03-24','2011-04-09','2011-04-25','2011-05-11','2011-05-27','2011-06-12',
  '2011-06-28','2011-07-14','2011-07-30','2011-08-15','2011-09-16','2011-10-02')))
```

Attach date to rasterstack;

```
ndvi <- setZ(ndvi, dt[,1], "SampleDate")
dates <- getZ(ndvi)
class(getZ(ndvi)) 
print(ndvi)

> print(ndvi)
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 5, 6, 30, 768  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent     : 267195, 267375, 4016985, 4017135  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names      :   layer.1,   layer.2,   layer.3,   layer.4,   layer.5,   layer.6,   layer.7,   layer.8,   layer.9,  layer.10,  layer.11,  layer.12,  layer.13,  layer.14,  layer.15, ... 
min values : -9158.809, -9507.726, -9987.505, -8785.589, -9790.658, -7778.071, -6953.068, -9046.727, -9599.514, -9873.984, -9835.690, -7611.904, -9644.684, -9440.149, -8011.084, ... 
max values :  9885.396,  9260.485,  9699.140,  9089.477,  9684.384,  7493.647,  9712.818,  9222.096,  9387.128,  9642.807,  9988.091,  9719.083,  9426.849,  9824.731,  9932.344, ... 
SampleDate  : 1988-01-04 - 2019-12-03 (range)
```

The following two functions are required to perform `BFAST` calculations on this stack.

```
a <- function(daily.ts) {
  s.month <- round(aggregate(as.zoo(daily.ts), as.yearmon, median), 0)
  s.month <- as.ts(s.month)
  return(s.month)
}

f <- function(data) {
  s <- bfastts(as.vector(data), dates, type = c("irregular"))
  s.d.linear <- round(na.approx(s), 0) 
  s.m.linear <- a(s.d.linear) #above function is used here
  result <- bfast(s.m.linear, h = 0.13, season="dummy", max.iter=2)
  return(c(result$Magnitude, result$Time))
}
```

Now I use `calc()` on the `ndvi` stack:

```
fbfast <- calc(ndvi, fun = f)
```

I get the following RasterBrick:

```
> fbfast
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 5, 6, 30, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent     : 267195, 267375, 4016985, 4017135  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      :   layer.1,   layer.2 
min values : -3915.188,   156.000 
max values :  6121.308,   196.000
```

The results are plotted below, where magnitude and time are shown by layer 1 and layer 2 respectively.

[image: plot(fbfast)]

Now I run above process in parallel using `Cluster` function from `Raster` package.

```
beginCluster()
z1 <- clusterR(ndvi, calc, args=list(fun=f), export='a')
```

The output is:

```
> z1
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 5, 6, 30, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent     : 267195, 267375, 4016985, 4017135  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      :   layer.1,   layer.2 
min values : -7434.631,    34.000 
max values :  4751.379,    59.000
```

If I `plot(z1)`
[image]

Now I do parallel processing using `parallel` package;

```
library(parallel)
c1 <- getCluster()
clusterExport(c1, "a")
z2 <- calc(ndvi, fun=function(x){ t(parApply(c1, x, 1, f))} )
```

Output is:

```
> z2
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 5, 6, 30, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent     : 267195, 267375, 4016985, 4017135  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      :   layer.1,   layer.2 
min values : -7434.631,    34.000 
max values :  4751.379,    59.000
```

The output is plotted;
[image]

The results of `z1` and `z2` (parallel processing) are same but different from `fbfast` (without parallel processing). The difference is not in the min and max values only but also the pixels where the changes in magnitude and time happen.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Aside from the reported min Max are the results comparable? Maybe inspect them manually in arc/q to see if the values are the same at various pts (or maybe stack them all together and use sampleRandom() in R). I've had r spit out raters with odd min/Max values that seem to be fine otherwise.

Comment: What other packages are you using? Can you make a reproducible example?

Comment: @Spacedman The code is edited and is reproducible now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export the dates variable as well because it is a global

```
beginCluster()
z1 <- clusterR(ndvi, calc, args=list(fun=f), export=c('a','dates')) 
endCluster()
```

or

```
c1 <- getCluster()
clusterExport(c1, c("a","dates"))
z2 <- calc(ndvi, fun=function(x){ t(parApply(c1, x, 1, f))} )
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I thought dates were attached to NDVI stack and therefore would not be exported to clusters. But you are right and it works fine now.